# In James Potter & the Vault of Destinies, what is the significance of Patches placing James and Ralph in Igor House?

Tags: harry-potter, fan-fiction

James Potter and the Vault of Destinies is the third novel in the James Potter series of Harry Potter fanfiction by G. Norman Lippert. The series, running into 5 novels, involves the adventures of Harry Potter's sons James and Albus Potter during school. In the third novel, due to an official assignment that Harry Potter gets as the Head Auror, the boys and a few other characters take a year long journey to the American wizarding school Alma Aleron. That school has six houses, or *societies*, as they are called:

1. Hermes House (Zombies)
2. Erebus House (Vampires)
3. Aphrodite House (Pixies)
4. Ares House (Werewolves)
5. Hephaestus House (Igors)
6. Apollo House (Bigfoots)

Now, instead of the Sorting as in Hogwarts, students can sign up for any of the houses they want, though some of them, like Zombies, demand certain strict and over-the-top pledge performances for admission. There is a tradition of asking Patches, the administration pet cat, as to which house a newcomer fits in, though there is no obligation to take its word. The Kneazle cat is supposed to have a sixth sense about such things.

Now when James Potter, Albus Potter their friends from Hogwarts consult Patches, it places James and his British friend Ralph Deedle in Igor House and Albus in Werewolf House, among others. While Albus' and other's placements are expected and welcomed, the case of James and Ralph puzzles all.

> “That can’t be right, Patches,” Zane said, frowning.
>
> Zane sighed. “It’s a glass beaker with electric bolts coming out of it, the symbol of Igor
> House. Patches, James is no Igor. Technomancy isn’t his thing. He’s an expert with defensive magic.
> He’s a Zombie all the way. Go on, go over to the cross-eyed skull.”
> To James’ surprise, the cat almost seemed to shake its head. It stayed on the Igor symbol, its
> left foot raised, its right planted right in the center of the engraved beaker.
> “I’m pretty sure I’m not an Igor,” James commented.
> “Yeah, well, stupid old cat,” Zane agreed, peering sidelong at Patches. “Good thing it isn’t
> like the Sorting Hat back at good ol’ Hoggies. You can pledge at whatever house you want,
> regardless of what he says.”
> “Do me now!” Albus proclaimed, stepping forward. “Let James go to the spods. What
> about me, Patches, ol’ buddy?”
> The cat regarded Albus coolly, and then put down his left paw. Slowly, he meandered along
> the symbols and stopped at one near the end. The shape was obvious enough that even James could
> make it out. It was a werewolf.
> Albus nodded, grinning. “Excellent. Wolves it is.”
> “What about Ralph, then?” Zane asked, pushing the bigger boy forward.
> Patches studied Ralph for a long time, his green eyes narrowed. Finally, he sat down, licked
> his flank a few times, got up again, and walked in a large circle. When he was done, his right foot
> rested on the beaker again.
> “Somebody’s putting catnip in your Tender Vittles, puss,” Zane said, shaking his head.
> “Ralph’s even less of an Igor than James here. He didn’t even take Technomancy when he had the
> chance.”
> “It’s true,” Ralph said to the cat. “I can’t even spell ‘technomancy’.”
> Patches lifted his nose and yawned again, as if bored.

-- *Alma Aleron*, Chapter 7, *James Potter & the Vault of Destinies*.

What follows is that James and Ralph sign up for Zombie House, but fail (spectacularly) at the house pledge, and are forced to join House Bigfoot, and continue there until they leave the school and US at the end of the year.

What is odd is that unlike numerous plot points in this series of novels, no explanation has been provided of this bewildering action of Patches. In fact, no mention has been made of this incident ever since in the series, to my reading.

It does turn out that somebody in Igor House is crucial to the plot of this book, but the character, now that I come to think of it, does not cross paths with James Potter at all in the literal sense. As such, there is nothing to justify placing James in his house on account of that connection, in some resemblance of the Harry-Voldemort one.

Now this is a series in which a seemingly unimportant scrap of paper written in Book 2 is brought up in the climax book 5 in a relevant, but not indispensable way, so I definitely expect the author to not have written a whole couple of pages introducing a (feline) character with no significance at all to the story.

What am I missing?